# What is the workflow that Hadoop uses to assign Master and Worker nodes through the Hadoop Configuration files?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I 'm a bit confused about how master and worker nodes are assigned to the respective connected machines (VMs) on the network in the cluster mode of Spark.

***My question is*** when i launch a Spark job (using Spark-submit) what is the process workflow that is responsible of assigning a master node and a worker node.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Driver and Executors requests containers from yarn to launch and do work.  Yarn takes care of the allocations for you so you don't need to worry about where the master(driver)/slave(executor) are allocated.

Comment: NodeManager runs the yarn containers to do work.  Datanodes hold HDFS file system.  You can use the SPARK UI to see where the containers were allocated or YARN UI.

Comment: ok i will check YARN UI ! thx